# I want the domain of a fluid simulation to abosrb the mesh (stop rendering splashes) as soon as it touches the bottom of that domain. Possible?

Tags: modeling, mesh

My fluid sim goes from top to bottom as a waterfall, but i want the water to be absorbed by the bottom of the domain as the fluid touches it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is what outflow fluid objects are for. Add a plane to the bottom of your simulation and set the fluid type of the plane to "Outflow".

Comment: thank you so much. i should've thought about that.